# Pseudo code for android

Tags: android

I am trying to write Pseudo Code for android. Here is what I am writing is it good?

```
MainActivity.java:
Start program
If Create account button is chosen
       Display activity_2
Else
       Display activity_3
```

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: write the pseudo code for each class

Comment: No I am talking about the goal you want to achieve. I mean work flow.

Comment: EG from MainActivity you have to go to LoginScreen or SignupScreen etc

Comment: yes that is what I want to do

Comment: so I think we can not make the pseudo code unless and until we do not know what is a task and what goal do you want to achieve.

Comment: from the main activity I want to go to login page or create account page

Comment: well in android you do not need to make such pseudo code but as it is a basis of your project you are better to do this or even better if you make the Flow chart.

Comment: the pseudo I posted above is good?

Comment: I edited it slightly below , on the basis of little information you provided to me . Else it is good ,  but it is not self descriptive .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainActivity.java:
Start Activity 
If already has account 
       Display LoginActivity Or logInButton which will take you to LoginActivity
Else
       Display SignUpActivity Or SingupButton which will take you to SignUpActivity
```

Comment: does the name of the activity has to be the same as I have created in my project?

Comment: but I will have 2 buttons in my main activity one create account the other login

Comment: yes , when you have two buttons for login and sign up , you need to hide one button at one time depending on the condition , if the user already has account , then the button for signup should get hide so that user should not click on this, but if the user do not have already created account then , the login button should be hidden from the user and only the Signup button should be visible to him